# transport header in sk_buff

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tcp, trafficshaping

Is it guaranteed that `skb->transport_header` is always correctly set on ingress path? Specifically, I'm setting a tc `qdisc` on interface, and attach to it `filter` with `tc` action; this path `qdisc->filter->action` exists before the packet hits TCP/IP stack, therefore I'm assuming that packet layers, networking and transport, should be set by the driver.

I was testing with `virtio_net` and `veth` drivers and it `skb_transport_header_was_set` always returns true, which I'm assuming means that the transport header is always initialized. But this may depend on the driver?